# Setting nested properties in Javascript / AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

I'm using AngularJS, and I want to set some config vars in my controller.

For example:

```
 $rootScope.config.showPosts.users = true;
    $rootScope.config.showPosts.businesses = false;
    $rootScope.config.showAds.businesses = true;
```

What is the correct way to declare "nested" properties like these? At the moment I have:

```
 $rootScope.config = [];
    $rootScope.config.showPosts = []; 
    $rootScope.config.showAds = [];
    // ^ as you can see, I am declaring each key of the array individually :( 
    $rootScope.config.showPosts.users = true;
    $rootScope.config.showPosts.businesses = false;
    $rootScope.config.showAds.businesses = true;
```

I don't have to declare every level of the array individually before I set it, do I? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use object litteral:

```js
rootScope.config = {
  showPosts: { 
    users: true,
    businesses: false
  },
  showAds: {
    businesses: true
  }
};
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to set a `property` over an `array`.

You wrote:

```
$rootScope.config.showPosts = [];
```

Then you try to write:

```
$rootScope.config.showPosts.users = true;
```

So `$rootScope.config.showPosts` should be an `object` instead of an `array` here. Change your code like this:

```
$rootScope.config = {};
$rootScope.config.showPosts = {}; 
$rootScope.config.showAds = {};
```

> I don't have to declare every level of the array individually before I set it, do I?

No you don't need to declare these objects individually, you can declare the whole configuration `object` in one statement like shown in the other answer.